# Wait for child process without using wait()

Tags: c, multithreading

When using `fork()`, is it possible to ensure that the child process executes before the parent without using `wait()` in the parent?

---

This is related to a homework problem in the [Process API chapter](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/cpu-api.pdf) of [Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/), a free online operating systems book.

The problem says:

> 3. Write another program using `fork()`. The child process should
>      print "hello"; the parent process should print "goodbye". You should
>      try to ensure that the child process always prints first; can you do
>      this *without* calling `wait()` in the parent?

Here's my solution using `wait()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // exit
#include <sys/wait.h> // wait
#include <unistd.h> // fork

int main(void) {
    int f = fork();
    if (f < 0) { // fork failed
        fprintf(stderr, "fork failed\n");
        exit(1);
    } else if (f == 0) { // child
        printf("hello\n");
    } else { // parent
        wait(NULL);
        printf("goodbye\n");
    }
}
```

After thinking about it, I decided the answer to the last question was "no, you can't", but then a later question seems to imply that you can:

> 5. Now write a program that uses `wait()` to wait for the child process
>      to finish in the parent. What does `wait()` return? What happens if
>      you use `wait()` in the child?

Am I interpreting the second question wrong? If not, how do you do what the first question asks? How can I make the child print first without using `wait()` in the parent?

Comment: Does calling `waitpid()`, or `waitid()` (or, on some systems, `wait3()` or `wait4()`) count as 'not calling `wait()`'?  How inventive do you want to get?  (You could open a pipe, close the write end, and execute a read on the read end; when the child exits, the write end of the pipe will be closed, so the parent will get EOF — 0 bytes read — and it knows that the child died, and all its children, etc.  That's not completely foolproof, but it depends on the context; do you know what the child processes will be doing?)

Comment: There are a lot of process synchronization mechanisms.  Another option (besides having the parent block on a read) is to have the child send the parent a signal after it has written the data (just calling `printf` is not enough to guarantee that the data is written).  Or have the parent wait for some event in the filesystem which the child triggers. (eg, parent tries to open a fifo, which will block until the child opens the fifo, but this is fundamentally the same as blocking on a read)

Comment: I'm assuming doing nothing until `SIGCHLD` doesn't count, even though the `siginfo_t` has a lot of useful info.

Comment: Note also that, in general, the `WNOWAIT` flag can often be used when you want to preserve `wait`ability.

Comment: You can use something like sleep() since you are doing this for a course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a pipe in the parent. After `fork`, close the write half in the parent and the read half in the child.

Then, `poll` for readability. Since the child never writes to it, it will wait until the child (and all grandchildren, unless you take special care) no longer exists, at which time `poll` will give a "read with hangup" response. (Alternatively, you could actually communicate over the pipe).

You should read about `O_CLOEXEC`. As a general rule, that flag should always be set unless you have a good reason to clear it.

Comment: could you explain in detail with example how to use poll() in this specific case?

Comment: @hoholee12 er, just the same as any other time? Have you read [the man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)?

Comment: With just the one pipe and no timeout, just reading from it would be simpler.  (It would always return EOF, of course.)

Comment: @DavisHerring Using `read` directly either requires a busy loop (which should be avoided at all costs) if you're nonblocking, or blocking (in which case you might as well just use `wait` in real-world scenarios) and looping on transient errors. This problem *does* come up in the real world, especially if you don't have `pidfd`.

Comment: @o11c: It’s legitimate to block on what might be only part of the child’s operation; the technique also generalizes to waiting on (actions of) non-children, aside from answering the pedagogical exercise.  I don’t know what transient errors something as simple as a pipe can produce.

Answer (score 10):

Just a few minutes ago, I sent an email to Remiz, the author of this book, and received the following response:

> Without calling wait() is hard, and not really the main point.
> What you did -- learning about signals on your own -- is a good sign,
> showing you will seek out deeper knowledge. Good for you!

> Later, you'll be able to use a shared memory segment, and
> either condition variables or semaphores, to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see why second question would imply that answer is "yes" to the first.

Yes there is plenty of solutions to obtain what asked, but of course I suspect that all are not in the "spirit" of the problem/question where the focus in on `fork/wait` primitives. The point is always to remember that you can't assume anything after a fork regarding the way processes ran relatively to each other.

To ensure the child process print first you need a kind of synchronization in between both processes, and there is a lot of system primitives that have a semantic of "communication" between processes (for example locks, semaphores, signals, etc). I doubt one of these is to be used her, as they are generally introduced slightly later in such a course.

Any other attempt only that will only rely on time assumption (like using `sleep` or loops to "slow" down the parent, etc) can lead to failure, means that you will not be able to prove that it will always succeed. Even if testing would probably show you that it seems correct, most of the runs you would try will not have the bad characteristics that lead to failure. Remember that except in realtime OSes, scheduling is almost an approximation of fair concurrency.

NOTE:

As Jonathan Leffler commented, I also suppose that using other `wait`-like primitives is forbidden (aka `wait4`, `waitpid`, etc) -- "spirit" argument.

Comment: My thought was that since it asks "Now write a program that uses `wait()` to wait for the child process to finish", it expected you to have written a program that _didn't_ use `wait()` for question 3.

Comment: But I can see how it might not imply that, since the rest of the question is about the particular behavior of `wait()`.

Comment: Exercises are not tightly linked like you think. Ex.5 doesn't suppose anything about provided solution in Ex.3. Ex.3 is about experiencing the waiting. Ex.5 is about values caught by a call to `wait` (questions are explicitly about this point).

Comment: I have found out what author wants to express by mailing him and post it in my answer : )

Answer (score 0):

You can use signals, which basically are being sent from the OS to the process. There are different types of signals. One that I am using here is SIGCHLD, which is a signal sent to the parent when the child exits. Normally by default it just ignores it. With the help of signal handlers you can determine how to handle that signal, or basically what to do when that signal is being sent.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

volatile int child_finished = 0;

void sigchild_handler(int sig) {
    child_finished = 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int rc = fork(); // rc in short for return code
    // normally when a SIGCHLD is being sent, default is to ignore it
    // SIGCHLD is basically the signal that the child is finished executing
    signal(SIGCHLD, sigchild_handler);
    if (rc < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "fork failed\n");
        exit(1); // terminates the program from wherever you are
    } else if (rc == 0) {
        printf("hello\n");
        exit(0);
    } else {
        while (!child_finished) {};
        printf("goodbye\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the sleep() function to sleep the parent process for some time, like in seconds, sleep(2). This will sleep or act like a wait for a number of seconds that you have passed as an argument in the sleep function.

Here is the code example:

```
   int main(int arg_counter, char *argv[]) {
    int child_process = fork();
    if(child_process < 0) {
        printf("Could not create child process");
        return 0;
    } else if(child_process == 0) {
        printf("Hello\n");
        return 0;
    } else {
        sleep(1);
        printf("Good Bye\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Do not forget to include <signal.h> library first.

Comment: Arbitrary sleep is usually a bad idea.  You can't ever know whether you've waited long enough, particularly on a heavily loaded host.